# Random error when accessing a folder under my inbox

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I'm relatively new to Python so don't judge me too rough :)
I have the below code that it suppose to connect to my inbox and move emails to another folder under the inbox.
Problem is that the first time I open Outlook, it works. After that it stop working and generate the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\learn!New Process Cerberus\OutlookCheck.py", line 72, in 
> identity_new_create = common_account.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Identity Registration']*
> File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6_Folders.py", line 103, in **getitem**
> return self.*get_good_object*(self.*oleobj*.Invoke(*(81, LCID, 1, 1, key)), "Item", '{00063006-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}')
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)*

After closing and opening again Outlook, program works again.
I have tried to delete temp files, search here for answers but nothing I tried worked and closing and opening Outlook every time does not represent a solution because the inbox is for office and it takes forever to sync with the server.
Please see below the code (I have cut the non related variables and lists from here as they are not the cause, I've tried):

```
import win32com.client as client
from pathlib import Path

common_account='WorkAccount'

try:
    outlook = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
except:
    home = str(Path.home()) + r'\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py'
    try:
        rem(Path(home))
    except:
        print('Could not perform a Python reset. Please delete temp files and folders yourself')
    try:
        outlook = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
    except:
        print('Could not link to Outlook')

namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
common_account = namespace.Folders[common_account]

common_inbox = common_account.Folders['Inbox'].Items
identity_new_create = common_account.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Identity Registration']

# Everything is perfect, program run flowless on the first run.
# After the first run I get the error above.
# After closing Outlook and opening it again, program runs again without error.

email = common_inbox.GetLast()
#Some other irellevant code
email.move(identity_new_create)
```

Later Edit:

I have found a way to bypass this error by searching for the folder each time I initialize Outlook but is not an elegant solution and require extra processing time and computing power. So the question is still on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following line of code throws an error at runtime:

> identity_new_create = common_account.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Identity Registration']

In that case I'd recommend iterating over all subfolders and checking the folder name, so you will find the target folder and at least be sure such folder exists there.

Also I've noticed the following line of code:

```
common_account.Folders['Inbox'].Items
```

Instead, use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default `Inbox` folder for the user who is currently logged on. Then you can get subfolders.

If you have got several accounts configured in Outlook you may use the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the `Store` objects in the current profile.

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
   EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder) 
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 If foldercount Then 
   For Each Folder In folders 
     Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
     EnumerateFolders Folder 
   Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene, I don't know how to use GetDefaultFolder in my case as I have 2 accounts. If I use GetDefaultFolder it automatically get the inbox from my other account :(

Comment: You can find the required account by iterating over all stores in the profile. Then use the `Store.GetDefaultFolder` method.

Comment: The solution you propose is way too advanced for me right now :) I'm still at the beginning in Python and I need to understand basic stuff first.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages. You just need to find out what methods and properties to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen cases where the line

```
common_account = namespace.Folders[common_account]
```

can return a PF folder from your Exchange account, which obviously does not have an Inbox folder. If you always want the default mailbox, you can use `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` instead of `common_account.Folders['Inbox']`.

You can also try to use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(common_account, olFolderInbox)` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I've already suggested that replacement.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, At this time this one I use but generates the error at second run of the program:
`common_account = namespace.Folders[common_account]` and after that the path to the folder from the inbox.
I will try the other one and let you know if works...

Comment: Is `common_account` a delegate Exchange mailbox? Is it visible in Outlook?